# How can i restrict parameters in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

i have one SP as below

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SAMPLE]
(
@ID varchar(20)=null,      

@FromDate varchar(20)=null,
@ToDate varchar(20)=null,
@LastDate varchar(20)=null,
@TransType varchar(50)  = '',
@ProviderId varchar(max)=null,
@Payerid varchar(max)=null,
@PageNum    int =1,
@PageSize int=10,
@Mode int=0,
@DateType  varchar(20)=null,
@SortOrder varchar(10)='',
@SortColumn varchar(50)=''
)
```

in procedure , some logic is implemented.

now i have to generate report in SSRS by using the above sp

i follwed the method like datasource creation , data set created by selecting query type as stored procedure , now it shows all above parameters. now i want to pass parameter only for id ,and it have to display data **if id is exist** in my table . but i have to display all those parameters but these parameters **should not ask** to pass the values for it.

can any body provide me solution for it. because i am facing strugle from 3 days onwards.

**remeMber** that it is not a drilldown or drill through or subreport. it is simple report created from Stored PROCEDURE

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Select each parameter in parameter list follow below steps:

1. go to parameter properties
2. select "Default Values" tab
3. here select "Specify Values"
4. give the value what you want
5. go to "general" tab select parameter as "Hidden" 
   Note: Follow above steps to those parameters that you don't want to select by user. 
    And for ID jus leave it as it is, so that the user can give when running the report.

Comment: Hemanth , according to you i selected parameter and then went to default values  here i select specify value , it is not accepting null  values ,if use parameter from expression it is showing error to me. here we cannot predict which value will be passed by the client. kindly provide solution and try to give some explanation. kindly note that parameter should be display in report and even though if we are not passing any value it should not show the error

Comment: okay.. In parameter properties general tab there will be three options like : 1.Allow Blank values, 2. Allow Null Values and 3.Allow multiple values. Select 1 and 2 options and run the report.. Here beside parameter prompt you can see a check box "Null" , you need to select that checkbox to pass null to that parameter... Is this helpful??

Comment: hemanth please available in communication because i am new to ssrs

Comment: Ya sure i will.. Was that above comment is helpfull to you?

Comment: hemanth 50% work is done but here if i select the check box allow null values then it is showing null check box along with parameters. i have to remove it . and some parameters asking  ,  ihow can i resolve it

Comment: Franklin.. we cannot remove null check box here.. and i have a doubt we need display all parameters when running the report so that user may or may not enter the value. Am i correct??

Comment: yes hemanth , in local it should show all parameters but while running report u have to show only specific parameters

Comment: ok so hide all parameters that you don't want to show and give default value to them.. if you want to give null as default, so look at the past comment of mine for the process..

Comment: k if i am not passing values for pagenum,pagesize and pmode it is giving error to me. then how can i rectify it

Comment: Ok as you are passing  1,10,0 in SP just pass these values in parameters default values as =1, =10,=0 respectively to Pnum, Psize and Pmode

Comment: k its working fine but here the probelm is if i am passing other than userid value(which not available in tabl) also it is dispalying the data .how can i rectify it

Comment: i hope there is no error at any cost many thanks hemanth  can u give ur mail-id then i will pass query to you

Comment: hemanth goodmorning ,yesterday my report is working fine now again it is showing the data in report even though reocord doens't exist in table

Comment: okay.. have you passed any default value for parameter ID? please check it out once...